# Carriage Return in Accordion Control Header - Silverlight 3.0

Tags: .net, xaml, silverlight-3.0, accordion, carriage-return

I've got an Accordion control in my Silverlight app, and I'd like to be able to insert a carriage return in the title of one of the AccordionItems.

I've tried inserting various symbols such as "&cf;" and "&br;"... but nothing has worked.

Appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered how to do it. Use the `&amp;#xa;` symbol and it works !